# AWS SQS messages stuck in flight when using Lambda triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have configured a queue with a DLQ with maximum receives value to 5.
The lambda was configured to pool 1000 messages in a 30 seconds batch window.
Whenever the lambda processor receives an invalid messages, it will throw an error
and I assumed the messages will eventually moved to DLQ when it reaches the receive count >= 5. But the messages are stuck in flight. And it seems the lambda processor wont retry those messages. Should I update the visibility timeout or any message attributes in the lambda processor just to make those messages visible again, retried and eventually moved to the DLQ?

Comment: It seems updating the visibility timeout (even with a same value) will make the messages appear again as available from being stuck inflight, will be retried and will make the received count increment. I though whenever you throw an error in the lambda, the messages will be retried again automatically, just like returning any value that automatically deletes the messages from the queue

Answer (score 1):

If the SQS Queue is KMS encrypted. Make sure that the Lambda IAM role has permissions to decrypt the KMS key.